# Error al insertar valores en sql server-VB6

Tags: sql-server, vb6

Estoy intentando insertar valores en una tabla desde un boton en visual basic 6 pero al correr el proceso me mandar el error, quiero creer que el error es por el dtpPicker pero creo que esta bien...

Este el parte del code

```
   Dim strSQL As String
   strSQL = "INSERT INTO FacturasPendientes (IdFactura,FechaFactura,CodigoProveedor,NombreProveedor," & _
                           "TotalFactura,FechaVencimiento,DiasDescuento,DescProntoPago,Pagado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
   Dim CmdCont As ADODB.Command
     Set CmdCont = New ADODB.Command
        With CmdCont
            Set .ActiveConnection = Cnn
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .CommandText = strSQL
            .Prepared = True
        End With
            'Creamos los Parametros
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("IdFactura", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TxtFactura.Text)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("FechaFactura", adDate, adParamInput, 50, dtpFactura.Value)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("CodigoProveedor", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TxtCodigoProveedor.Text)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("NombreProveedor", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, txtProveedor.Text)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("TotalFactura", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, m_importe3)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("FechaVencimiento", adDate, adParamInput, FechaFinal)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("DiasDescuento", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, txtDias.Text)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("DescProntoPago", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, txtDescuento.Text)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("Pagado", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, 0)

     CmdCont.Execute
```

Al ejecutar me manda este error

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Ya agrande los tipos de datos en la db, y asigne los mismo que estoy asignando en el code.

Comment: Si mal no entiendo estas convirtiendo a DATETIME algo que le estas dando formato solo DATE (yyyy-MM-dd).

Comment: Corrige eso. Hay que parametrizar las consultas a menos de que quieras sufrir un ataque de inyección de sql y dar control total de tu servidor a algún atacante.

Comment: Estoy utilizando visual basic 6, creo que no se puede parametrizar en este lenguaje.. gual lo cambio

Comment: El clase SqlCommand tiene una collection llamada Parameters .  Puede añade parametros con .add() o .addWithValue()

Comment: @Duston el sqlcommand no lo detecta visual basic 6, o tal vez yo estoy perdido

Comment: @LuisCazares ya agrege el cambio pero ahora me mando 

String or binary data would truncated, pero esto es problema del concatenado pero no logro agregarlo

Comment: Valida la longitud de los valores que estás enviando para que no superen la longitud de las columnas de la tabla. Sin definición de tablas, ni valores de muestra es imposible saber. También actualiza tu código para verlo parametrizado en vez de estar concatenando valores.

Comment: En VB6 no existe el `.add()` o `.addWithValue()`. Necesita usar `.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter()`

Comment: Ya hice las modificaciones que me recomendaron pero ahora me atore con otra cosa